# Character Encoding Issue in Creating a Persistent View with Non-ASCII (Greek Characters) in Databricks

Tags: azure, encoding, databricks

I have tried to create a persistent view with a simple select statement that just has a word with greek characters.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW misc.XX AS 
SELECT 'ΤΕΣΤ'
```

If I try to select that view, I get ???? instead of the word I typed.

[image: Select Statement]

The issue seems to be that the view definition is not saved correctly.

[image: View Details]

Are there any workarounds here? The problem happens only with views, when writing as table, characters appear as expected.

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula yes, azure databricks

Comment: How was the view created? What you posted only happens when you try to read non-Unicode text with the wrong non-Unicode codepage. In all Unicode encodings characters outside the 7-bit ASCII range use 2 or more bytes. If you tried to use a *Unicode* encoding, you'd get  �, the Unicode replacement character. The fact that ΤΕΣΤ became ???? means the definition was stored as non-ASCII from the start.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The view was created using a standard SQL create view statement. I aslo tried to specify TBLPROPERTIES like ('store.charset'='utf8', 'retrieve.charset'='utf8') and yet the Greek characters display as question marks.

Comment: Using what tool? A local editor? An Azure Web page? Something else? As you said, data doesn't get mangled, only the view *definition*. It's quite likely the definition was mangled by the editor

Comment: The fact you got four `?` instead of 8 means the definition was treated as ASCII, probably from the start, ie the editor. Otherwise you'd see something like `Î¤ÎÎ£Î¤`. That's how the UTF8 bytes appear if they're read as Latin1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that we were storing view in the Hive Metastore (HMS). It's important to note that HMS in Databricks has a limitation: it cannot accommodate non-ASCII characters within view definitions.

However, if you opt for Unity Catalog, this limitation no longer applies, and you can freely work with non-ASCII characters in your view definitions.

---

For those constrained by the use of HMS, there is a potential workaround available. You can store text in a hex-encoded format using UTF-8 encoding.

1. Start by encoding the text in a hex format using UTF-8 encoding. To do this, you can use the following SQL command:

```
SELECT hex(encode("ΤΕΣΤ", "UTF-8")); --> CEA4CE95CEA3CEA4
```

2. Next, take the output from the command above and save it within a view definition. This can be achieved by creating or replacing a view such as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW misc.TEST AS
SELECT decode(unhex('CEA4CE95CEA3CEA4'), 'UTF-8') AS col1;
```

3. You can now query the view and get non-ASCII characters.

Answer (score 1):

- I have tried the below Workaround creating a table and then a view referencing that table.
- I am storing the Greek characters in a table and then querying that data through a view.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

- I have also an example of handling **non-ASCII** characters, such as Greek characters, in Azure Databricks using pyspark.
- In the below code I am Writing the DataFrame to a table with
  appropriate encoding settings.

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("handling-non-ascii-characters") \
    .getOrCreate()
data = [('ΤΕΣΤ',)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['my_column'])
df.show()
df.write.option("encoding", "UTF-8").saveAsTable("misc.my_table02")
spark.sql("CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW misc.my_view02 AS SELECT my_column FROM misc.my_table02")
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM misc.my_view02").show()
spark.sql("DESCRIBE TABLE EXTENDED misc.my_table02").show()
```

[image]